# Swift 3 : How can I go to the previous ViewController and reload it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to go back to the previous view controller and when I go back to this page, I need to reload the view controller. I used viewWillAppaer in the A view controller, but it doesn't work when I call the `popViewController` in B view controller.

I used this code in B viewController :

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: `viewWillAppear` of view controller A should be triggered after popping view controller B and going back to view controller A, are you sure it wasn't?

Comment: I'm using the viewwillappear function in A, but popViewController just calls the page and doesn't work with it.

Comment: have you did any code in viewDidLoad that you want after coming back from the B viewController?

Comment: It should trigger `viewWillAppear` when you are coming back to  previous view controller. Please make sure you are  using `viewWillAppear`,  not `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: @winnervswinner have you tested using breakpoints?

Comment: It definitely calls [`viewWillAppear(_ animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsviewcontroller/1434415-viewwillappear) when you pop back to it (or, when doing an interactive swipe from left edge, when you start the swipe, even if you don't eventually complete it). Note, it's neither `viewWillAppaer` (as suggested in your question) nor `viewwillappear` (as suggested in your comment). So, if it's not getting called, there's something unrelated going on (e.g. you forgot to specify the base class for first scene, you mistyped the method signature, etc.).

Comment: If you're still having a problem, I'd suggest you create a [simple blank project with two scenes that reproduces the problem you're describing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and upload that somewhere for us to take a look at it.

Comment: BTW, if doing storyboards, you can also use unwind segue, so the caller is informed when you pop back to it. Or you can set up delegate-protocol pattern (the standard way to pass data back). But I'd suggest you figure out what's going on here, because there might be some more fundamental problem, as `viewDidAppear(_ animated:)` would normally be called.

Comment: I realized that I need to use dismiss function after this. now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're presenting the `ViewControllers` on a `NavigationController`? What could be happening is you're presenting the `ViewController` on top of `ViewController` A therefor to dismiss it you would need to call `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`
 on `ViewController` B.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

NavigationController guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html

Comment: dismiss function worked after popViewController. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to pop a navigation controller, you need to make sure you first pushed the navigation controller onto the navigation stack. Otherwise, you can use

```
present(UIViewController)
dismiss(UIViewController)
```